# Angular2 routing to a terminal route below a route param

Tags: routes, angular, router, parameters, siblings

I have an interesting routing challenge with Angular2 that I would like to solicit ideas about.  I have a route that in the URL I need to look like this:

```
.../item/editor/[trigger]/options/list
```

Where the bracketed [trigger] refers to a RouteParam.  So the RouteConfig for the path to the "editor" component looks like this:

```
@RouteConfig([{
    path: '/editor/:trigger/...', name: 'Editor', component: ItemEditor
},
...
])
```

In the template for the parent of the editor component, I have a router-link like this:

```
[routerLink]="['./Editor', {trigger: 'button'}]"
```

But I do not know how to specify the remaining path past the route param in the router link.  What I need is that when the Editor component is navigated to, it uses the "trigger" route param to configure one part of its template (via DynamicComponentLoader, which is really cool btw), AND fill a router-outlet ('./Options/List') in the same template with the contents identified by the remaining part of the route  (./Options/List) tacked on in the RouteConfig in the Editor component itself.

When I try to navigate using the router link above I get the router error about the link not being a terminal instruction.  I thought I might be able change the router link to be ['./Editor/Options/List', {trigger: 'button'}] or something similar with a placeholder for :trigger in the path, but that results in an error indicating that I haven't provided the trigger value for the route.

I thought I might try to use sibling router-outlets in the Editor component to solve this, but the ng2 team has been conspicuously silent about that capability since they removed it back in 06/2015.  At least I have not found a single example of such.

It's entirely possible that I am not thinking about this correctly.  Does anybody have any ideas about how to solve this?  Example of sibling router-outlets?  anyone?

Regards.  I'm on 2.0.0-beta.0.

Comment: You mean something like `[routerLink]="['./Editor', {trigger: 'button'}, 'Options', 'List']"`?

Comment: @EricMartinez wow, if that's all it is, i'll be extremely embarrassed.  Gonna try it first thing this morning.  If you'll post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.